# List Comprehension for Strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists as shown below. I want to find whether the strings inside the first list are in any of the strings in the second list. For some reason, I get an empty list when I try to run this.

For example: in `list5`, string `'apple'` is in `list6`'s `'I ate an apple'`.

```
list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango']
print ([x for i,x in enumerate(list5) if x in list6])
```

The exact same things run smoothly for a list of integers. Is there a different way of going through the strings?

```
list7 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list8 = [1, 2]
print ([x for i,x in enumerate(list7) if x in list8])
```

Comment: You're checking if 'apple' itself is a member of list6, you want to check if 'apple' is a substring of any string in list6

Comment: Will you always be dealing with single words from the first string list? Could you have `['an apple', 'mango', 'sherbert']` for example in the first list and expect to match `'an apple'` in any of the strings in the second list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are checking if `apple` is in the list but you want to check if any string in the list contains apple

```
list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango']
[x for x in list5 if any(x in item for item in list6)]
#['apple', 'mango']
```

## EDIT

This creates a list of list in which contain the indexes of the sentence in the second list, which contain the word from the first list

```
list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango', '2 apple', 'big apple', 'big mango']
[[i for i, sentence in enumerate(list6) if x in sentence] for x in list5]
#[[0, 1, 3, 4], [2, 5], []]
```

As I said in my comment a dictionary would be better in this situation

```
{x:[i for i,sen in enumerate(list6) if x in sen] for x in list5}
#{'apple': [0, 1, 3, 4], 'mango': [2, 5], 'sherbet': []}
```

And if only exact matches should be stored you can use this, but this does not work if the first list does not only contain words, for example if `list5` contains "an apple" this does NOT work

```
{x:[i for i,sen in enumerate(list6) if any(x==item for item in sen.split())] for x in list5}
#{'apple': [0, 3, 4], 'mango': [2, 5], 'sherbet': []}
```

Comment: I want to know at what index is apple occurring in list6 and 'any' method doesn't give me all the instances as well. Is there a way in which I get all the instances and their index?

Comment: What do you mean with all instances? should apple be two times in the output? Please show us how your desired output should look like

Comment: What if the a string contains two of the words for example 'I ate an apple and a mango'?

Comment: The example given doesn't have multiple instances but what if it is like. list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango', '2 apple', 'big apple', 'big mango']. I want to get [0,3,4] for apple and [2, 5] for mango. Basically their respective indexes in that specific list. Just to clarify when I say indexes, I mean of the whole string. Hope I'm making sense

Comment: alright understood what you mean does the output have to be a list? Because a dictionary would be suited better for this sth like {"apple":[3,4,5]}

Comment: Awesome,it worked! One last question, I want to find values of a third list using these index values. list7 = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl' ]. I would like to get values apple:['ab', 'gh', 'ij'] and mango:['ef', 'kl'] corresponding to their index values 0,3,4 and 2,5 respectively. Thanks you so much for the help.

Comment: Use list7[i] instead of i then :) 
Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking if `x` is a member of `list6`, when it seems like you want to know if `x` is a substring of any member in `list6`. You can do this using Python's `reduce` method (in `functools` with Python 3).

```
list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango']

from functools import reduce
print([x for x in list5
         if reduce(lambda exist, s: exist or (x in s), list6, False)])
# ['apple', 'mango']
```

The `reduce` call is iterating through all members of `list6` and checking if `x` is a substring, then or'ing those results against `exist` (which defaults to `False` here) to return `True` if it's found at least once. See the Python3 documentation for [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for a better idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for set intersection in which case I would just go around and use sets instead of lists and use the intersection operator instead of a loop, like this `a & b` where a and b are sets.

But you example makes it seem like you are looking for substrings from list5 in each of the strings in list6, which is a totally different probably and one we would need more information about what your expected output would be to help you more.

Also BTW, you don't need to use enumerate since you aren't using the value from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!python3

import re

list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango']

for item in list6:
    for substr in list5:
        if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(substr) + r"\b", item):
            print('"' + substr + '"' + ' is in ' + '"' + item + '"')

'''
# output
"apple" is in "I ate an apple"
"mango" is in "I love mango"
'''

list7 = [1, 2, 3, 4,5]
list8 = [1,2]

for substr in list8:
    if substr in list7:
        print(substr, 'is in', list7)

'''
# output
1 is in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2 is in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
'''
```

Comment: Whoever down voted me should explain themselves. This code works. it may not be the best code but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call a function in your list comprehension.

It is not a one-liner, but the logic is clear and it will short-circuit as soon as a match is found.

```
list5 = ['apple', 'mango', 'sherbet']
list6 = ['I ate an apple', 'I ate two apples', 'I love mango']

def find_word(x, sentences):
    for item in sentences:
        if x in item:
            return x

res = [x for x in list5 if find_word(x, list6)]

# ['apple', 'mango']
```